# Check if a specific function is inlined - Intel compiler

Tags: c, binaryfiles, icc

I have C/C++ binary libraries (*.dll, *.sys) the obj files they consist of, and their symbols (pdb), but not the source code nor map files.
According to the symbols they were built by the Intel compiler (for windows).

Is there any way to check if a specific function is inlined?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind that function *calls* are inlined, it's not really a property of the function itself. I don't know the file formats, but you should be able to look through the executable functions and find places the symbol file's line-number info jumps into different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ICC is particularly aggressive with inlining, and in many cases when a function is declared as `inline` (and especially if it's `__forceinline`'d on MSVC), it'll actually throw an error during the compilation stage if it's unable to inline it (depending, obviously, on your project compilation settings).

That said, honestly the only way you'll be able to do what you need is to attach a debugger, pause the app in MSVC, switch to ASM view, and search for calls to the function you're looking for's name (you say C/C++, it makes a difference which as with C++ you'll have to search for the mangled name). If you find calls to the function (`call _myFunc`), it's not inlined.

Otherwise, if you know where to look, browse through the ASM to find the *caller* function, and check its source to verify that a call to the *callee* either is or isn't there.

It may sound rather daunting, but it's actually easy enough and just a `ctrl+f` away.